# Null Pointer Exception Log Cat Error

Tags: java, android, logcat

In my project file and source-code there are no errors. No build errors, no project errors, no syntax errors... and for some reason when i run my application on the emulator it crashes.
HERE is the Log Cat information - I've searched everything but with no errors being flagged once it is compiled I'm having a hard time figuring out why the application is crashing.

Thanks in advance!

This is the source code for activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
                    android:text="Convert" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editDecimal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"
                    android:maxLength="9" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:text="Enter the decimal value to be converted :)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editDecimal"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="Decimal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonConvert"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
                    android:text="Binary"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editBinary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the source code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

   // Set the Tab name and Activity
   // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

---

**LOG CAT**

```
09-14 00:39:23.213: D/AndroidRuntime(774): Shutting down VM
09-14 00:39:23.213: W/dalvikvm(774): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.overworldinnovations.datatool/com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-14 00:39:23.333: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  ... 11 more
09-14 00:39:23.353: D/dalvikvm(774): GC_CONCURRENT freed 118K, 9% free 2704K/2944K, paused 8ms+65ms, total 166ms
09-14 00:43:31.776: D/AndroidRuntime(817): Shutting down VM
09-14 00:43:31.776: W/dalvikvm(817): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.overworldinnovations.datatool/com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-14 00:43:31.836: E/AndroidRuntime(817):  ... 11 more
09-14 00:43:31.976: D/dalvikvm(817): GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 8% free 2678K/2908K, paused 9ms+43ms, total 187ms
```

Comment: Post `com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity` content, there is a `NPE` in `TabHost.addTab` method.

Comment: Added the source code! Thanks for the read!

Comment: This is very obviously a `NullPointerException`, not an "unknown error". The problem is on line 41 of MainActivity.java.

Comment: @user3681591 which line is `line 41` ?

Comment: 'tabHost.addTab(tab1);' is line 41 and if i do not know the error it's unknown so my title description is accurate.

Comment: @user3681591 If you read the full logcat, the error is very clear. Do you need flashing neon lights?

Comment: Then your issue is either with `tab1` being `null` or `tabHost` being `null`. If I were you, I'd check to see what `TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");` is doing. I'd also check to see  what `TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);` is doing.

Comment: @erad Since the NPE occurs inside the call to `addTab()`, the diagnosis isn't quite that clear cut.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your stacktrace and the [`TabHost.addTab`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/widget/TabHost.java#TabHost.addTab%28android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec%29) source code. You are missing a `TabWidget` with id `@android:id/tabs` inside your `TabHost`.

If you want to use a `TabHost` you must have a layout with this prototype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Don't forget to call [`mTabHost.setup();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setup()) before adding tabs! Like:**

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();
// Add your tabs now
```

**Edit**: Because you are using `Tab.setContent(Intent i)` it's mandatory to call `TabHost.setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)` instead of `TabHost.setup()`.

So it i'll be:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(this);
// Add your tabs now
```

More details: http://blog.vogella.com/2011/05/17/android-tabs/

But `TabHost` is "deprecated", i recommend you to use the `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` with `ActionBarActivity` and using `Fragments`.

Take a look at this tutorial if you want to migrate: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: I just posted my .XML file and it shows that i actually do have a TabWidget with id @android:id/tabs inside your TabHost. And I'm still getting the NPE :/

Comment: Edited my answer with one detail. According with the documentation you must call `tabHost.setup()` before adding your tabs.

Comment: I places tabHost.setup(); in and now i got the error -----          "09-14 01:40:51.960: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.overworldinnovations.datatool/com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

Comment: Try to call `setup(this)`, to add an `Tab` that launchs an `Activity` you must suply a `LocalActivityManager`. If you don't really need the `ActionBar`, i suggest to extends `TabActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`. `TabActivity` calls `setup` implicity.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Null Pointer Exception.

Based on your log, if I were you, I'd take a good look at `com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)` (the `onCreate()` method of your `MainActivity` on line 41)

There is likely some issue in your `onCreate()` method where some variable you are trying to use is `null`. (I can't be for certain though since I don't know what is on line 41 of your `onCreate()`)

According to the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) for Null Pointer Exceptions:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an
> object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a
>   null object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

Comment: /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);     this is lines 40-43. Thanks for the read!